# SOQL query Contacts x Campaigns by filter with Events on the Contacts

Tags: soql

I'm trying to write an SOQL in order to get a Contact list (including which Campaigns those contacts are in) filtered by Events Subjects on the contacts. Essentially I want to see which Campaign is influencing the Events..This .

I wrote the following

```
   SELECT 
Id,Name,title,email,
        (Select Id,Subject,ActivityDate,DiscoveryCallAuto__c From Events Where CreatedById ='XXX' AND Inbound_lead__c = FALSE AND Subject = 'Discoverycall' ) 
        FROM Contact
```

This in itself works but but from here I don't know how to add the SOQL for the Campaign Object. I'm not sure also if the order of the Nesting would be changed.

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your question needs rephrasing. First part says, you are just trying to query. Second part says you are trying to insert. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @metasync ok, I have rephrased the question and removed insert. There is no inserting I want to do.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Relationship Query already to select the related Event records. You can do the same to get to the related Campaign records however there is one important caveat - the Contact <-> Campaign connection is through the CampaignMember object.

Something like:

```
select id, name, title, email,
  (select id, Campaign.id, Campaign.Name from CampaignMembers) ...
```

See the link below if you need help understanding Relationship Names and relationship queries in general...
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

Comment: Matt, thank you for input here.

Yes, I do know that the Contact is linked to Campaigns via the CampaignMember.

Given the Contact is the parant to the Event object & as well as the Parent to the Campaign member object, I'm wondering how to go about doing this.

If the event was linked to the CampaignMember, it would be simple, because it would writing a SOQL which looks only one way down the hierarchy: Contact -> CampaignMember -> Event. However, its not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in single SOQL statement.  You will need to write Apex with at least two queries and some collections (Maps, Sets and/or Lists) to build the additional queries and to relate the contacts+events to the campaigns.

Example

1. Query the contacts + events.
2. Loop through the contacts to build a Set of contact IDs.
3. Query for campaign members + campaign fields
4. Build a Map to relate the contact to the campaign using the campaign member records.

UPDATE: If you're using REST API, you could make a [composite request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite_post.htm)

> Executes a series of REST API requests in a single call. You can use
> the output of one request as the input to a subsequent request

Comment: Hey David

Thanks for the tips. I do not have Apex in our SF org. 
I'm using SOQL to pull data in order to do further analysis and reporting.

Comment: Ah, well you could use REST API to make a composite request.  Otherwise, you'll have to do steps 2 & 4 in your external application.

Comment: Hello David,
Thanks for suggesting a work around here. I reckon this is above and beyond my skill level with salesforce and code. Looking into it, it seems that a composite request needs to be written in JSON, which I really don't know.

I think for now, I'll SOQL separately various objects and then find the patterns and analysis to answer what I'm looking with Excel.